# search 5 product in mysql and echo 4 different rows

Tags: mysql

im Ivica and im new here.

i need form with 5 places for product codes. Every product have 4 rows (name, perex, amount, library_id) in database and i want place solution every products to different places.

Can help?

Sorry for my english.

DB CODE:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Nepodařilo se připojit k MySQL serveru (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')    '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT library_id, amount, name, perex, extId 
FROM product_item, main_library, product_item_price, product_text 
WHERE product_item.product_id = main_library.main_id 
AND product_item.id = product_item_price.item_id 
AND product_item.product_id = product_text.product_id 
AND product_item_price.level_id = 1  AND product_item.extId = '$test'");

echo 'Z databaze jsme ziskali ' . $sql->num_rows . ' radku.';
echo "</br>";
while ($produkt = $sql->fetch_assoc())
{
printf($produkt['name']);
echo "</br>";
printf($produkt['perex']);
echo "</br>";
printf($produkt['amount']);
echo "</br>";
}
$sql->free_result();

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: i beginer with php and this mysql query is first ever query, :-) I dont know, how i do the other and echo result out of this database <?php ?>. If i do any another example <?php echo printf($produkt['perex']);?> nothing do. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Example: I use form and try find 3 different products and these "name", "perex" and "amount" by ID and need to put those results in some tables with any places on page.

FORM:

```
<form action="search.php" method="REQUEST"> 
<b>Find product:</b> 
<input type="text" name="productID" size="50">
<input type="text" name="productID2" size="50">
<input type="text" name="productID3" size="50">
<br> 
<input type="submit" value="Search"> </form>
```

TABLE:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td>productID name</td>
      <td>productID name</td>
      <td>productID name</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
      <td>productID2 perex</td>
      <td>productID2 perex</td>
      <td>productID2 perex</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
      <td>productID3 amount</td>
      <td>productID3 amount</td>
      <td>productID3 amount</td>
  <tr>
  </table>
```

MYSQL look this:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT library_id, amount, name, perex, extId 
FROM product_item, main_library, product_item_price, product_text 
WHERE product_item.product_id = main_library.main_id 
AND product_item.id = product_item_price.item_id 
AND product_item.product_id = product_text.product_id 
AND product_item_price.level_id = 1 
AND (product_item.extId = '$_REQUEST[productID]' 
OR product_item.extId = '$_REQUEST[productID2]' 
OR product_item.extId = '$_REQUEST[productID3]')");
```

Can help?

Ivica